# How to change border circle bullets in css style?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this bullet when using `<li>` tag with `list-style: circle`:

[image]

How can I change the border of the circle with css? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the styling of that circle, but you can apply `list-style: none;` to the list to hide the list icon and add circle elements using `li: before` pseudo elements, having the settings as below or similar:

```css
ul {
list-style: none;
}
li {
position: relative;
}
li:before {
position: absolute;
left: -1.2em;
bottom: 0.3em;
content: ' ';
display: block;
width: 0.45em;
height: 0.45em;
border: 2px solid lightblue;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```